# Why does a file placed in windows startup folder not execute the file each time I start my system ?

Tags: windows, boot

I have a file on Windows 8.1 in the following location:
    C:\Users\Ciaran\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

I want a file that I've put into this location to run each time Windows starts. The folder above is the 'start up' folder and therefore should do what I want, and it used to work. For some reason, unknown to me, this no longer works. Does anybody have any idea why this might be?

All the best,

Comment: startup only fires on logon, not on unlock, so make sure that you are logging into a new session (not resuming from sleep/hibernate and then unlocking a previously logged in session). confirm the file permissions, and that it executes when you run it explicitly. if its a lnk/shortcut make sure it still points to the app in question. you can check sysinternals Autoruns to confirm that its expected to launch on login.

Comment: Actually this makes a lot of sense since I use hibernate quite regularly. Thanks